# Are image classification nets independent of input size ? Which ones?

Tags: computer-vision, image-recognition, object-detection

Most models I have seen have a dense layer at the exit of the network with a softmax function or a relu sometimes, so I thought this was confusing:

> The major hurdle for going from image classification to object detection is fixed size input requirement to the network because of existing fully connected layers.

[Source](https://towardsdatascience.com/region-of-interest-pooling-f7c637f409af)